# Selecting an itunes libary message clarification

Tags: itunes

I received a new message when syncing my iphone to my PC with a USB cable.  I have done this for years with out such question.

"iTunes needs a library to continue.  you may choose an existing itunes library or create a new one"

the message gives an option of choosing or creating but when you click choose, it is not clear which file to choose.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would be helpful to know the OS you are using, if you have made ANY changes to the PC lately, and what you have researched or tried so far. You can **[edit]** your question to improve it with details.

Answer (score 7):

You can get this message one of two ways, either iTunes cannot locate your iTunes library, because you've moved it, or you pressed <kbd>shift</kbd> while opening iTunes.

You can use the choose button to locate your library, but if you are using music that is not stored in the library folder, and have moved them at all, the music files themselves may need to be re-located, which is a part manual part automatic process.

If you need re-locate any of the music files, just try to play one, if it needs to be re-located you'll get a message asking you to browse for it, do so, and if your music is stored in the same parent directory iTunes may be able to automatically find the rest.